# Can 4G be used on a 3G phone if 4G bands are supported?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 4g, micromax-a350

I have a 3G phone but it supports the 4G band (1800 MHz) which is available in my area. Is there any way I can enable my phone to support 4G?

I went to `*#*#4636#*#*`, and there **is** an LTE option, but I cannot select it. Each time I select it, the option changes to WCDMA Only or WCDMA Preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your phone called the Micromax a350 Canvas Knight? If so, I'm sorry, but your phone DOESN'T support 4G, [according to the specs sheet found on gsmarena.](http://www.gsmarena.com/micromax_a350_canvas_knight-5995.php)

Don't be excited to see the LTE in the `*#*#4636#*#*` options, because that menu lists all the possible bands there is, although your phone *might* not support *all* or *some* of them.

The maximum you can connect to is 3G, you therefore can't use the 4G in your area. The limitation is not software-related. It is hardware-related. The hardware component responsible for supporting 4G band isn't in your phone.